# Htaccess, почему у меня происходит редирект?

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, чпу

В .htaccess есть правило:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/name $1/?url=name  [L,QSA]
```

По задумке при запросе адреса `www.site.ru/dir/name` должен отображаться контент `www.site.ru/dir/?url=name`, но происходит редирект на `www.site.ru/dir/?url=name`

Answer (score 1):

Я не эксперт в Mod_Rewrite, но попробуйте поменять правило на следующее, возможно QSA лишнее, не совсем понимаю назначение этой директивы, у себя на сайтах обхожусь без нее:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(dir)/(name)/?$ $1/$2/?url=$3  [L,QSA]
```

Если не поможет, почитайте здесь [www.htaccess.net.ru](http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/mod_rewrite/Primer-RewriteRule.php)

Сам настраивал по материалам с этого сайта

Comment: Лучше вот это рекомендовать к чтению, если не поможет:  
http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/